# How to populate a google maps autocomplete search result with custom options on an interactive map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

So I'm stuck on this - I'm working on building a site that shows activities near a user dependent on the location they input i.e. if I put in "Kent, London" or a postcode into the search box, it'll show an interactive map with pins and/or a list that details nearby activities - essentially a similar function to how Trivago shows hotels when you put in a location and you can view the list/show the map.

I've managed so far to get an autocomplete function working on-site by creating an input box and calling the Google Maps API like so:

```
    <head>
...
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
...
</body>
```

And then calling a JS function:

```
    function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

However I don't know how to:

1. Get the search box to, upon a user hitting enter OR clicking the
       "search" button, display a page with an interactive map - to be
       honest I think this will be an onClick function or something along
       the lines if someone can clarify and provide me with the correct
       syntax on opening a new page with this?

   2. On this new page - I would want the interactive map with the data displayed dependent on the location the user entered - I can
      appreciate not all locations will work and I am not planning on
      covering the entire nation - instead I want to start off with
      one-two locations and list activities on a map dependent on them -
      so if I enter "Kent" for example or even a postcode - how would I
      get a map to display?
   3. As for the activities themselves I know what activities I want to put in but what would be the correct way to input and call these in accordance to the above requirements? Would I need to create and then import them from a Database of some sort? Could these populate on the map as pins and when you click on the pins more information is displayed? Or as a list on the side or below the map?

Appreciate any help I can appreciate this is a complex question and in no way do I intend to do something on the scale of say Trivago - more of a super toned down version within the same spirit of their search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start with the different sample code provided by [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/).

Here is the example code on how to use [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

```
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));

  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }



    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
      url: place.icon,
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
    }));
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
}
```

Now, you can make this code as your starting point, then try to apply here the different function that you want your application do.